# How to edit position of zoom when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a table with images in it, and have a css that zoom an image on hover. Images that are placed below scroll line are zooming incorrectly.

If I remove `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`, everything works. But when the image is zoomed, it is not coming out of table. I need the image to go beyond the table when zoomed.

```css
.zoom {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 .zoom:hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
   transform: scale(4); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
 }
  tbody {
    display:block;
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  thead {
    background-color: rgb(67, 116, 185);
    color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
  }
  thead, tfoot, tbody tr {
      display:table;
      width:100%;
      table-layout:fixed;
      text-align: center;
  }
  p.sub {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 12%">image</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">ok</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 12%" class="zoom"><img src="https://www.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/module-6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"/></th>
          <td style="width: 7%"> ff </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 12%" class="zoom"><img src="https://www.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/module-6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"/></th>
          <td style="width: 7%"> ff </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 12%" class="zoom"><img src="https://www.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/module-6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"/></th>
          <td style="width: 7%"> ff </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 12%" class="zoom"><img src="https://www.bigstockphoto.com/images/homepage/module-6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"/></th>
          <td style="width: 7%"> ff </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for : [Codepen link for the solution](https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/eYNvvjO?editors=0100)

The main issue was you are zooming out the container which is the parent instead of the child which is the image.

Changes I did to parent element :

```
th {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Changes I did to child component :

```
.zoom {
 padding: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 transition: transform .5s; /* Animation */
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Actually I need the image to go beyond the table when zoomed. For this purpose i added position: relative; and position: absolute; into zoom class. Because of this, the pictures that are below the scroll line are not displayed correctly, as they are attached to the position below

Comment: "the pictures that are below the scroll line are not displayed correctly". May I know what is the correct thing you are looking for? Because if you zoom the image 4 times, it will obviously cover the image below it.

Comment: This is the correct zoom of the picture https://ibb.co/Y7xpY2H 
and this is the thing that i am trying to explain https://ibb.co/Y7xpY2H

Comment: The images thats in tbody { height:500px; } this range display correctly, others when I scroll up trying to zoom in position bellow.